# How to refer to a place by number

Tags: numbers

Suppose I'm at a bank and all the service counters are numbered. How can you say something like:

> Please come to counter number 2.

If all the counters were active and numbered in order then I guess I could say:

> 2番目のカウンタに来てください。

Is this natural?

But if counter number 2 is closed then the second counter would be counter number 3. So how can I refer to the counter by it's labelled number rather than it's position in a sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「2番窓口{ばんまどぐち}」

would be the most common way to refer to it.  In banks, 「窓口」 would be far more common than 「カウンター」.

It would sound pretty wordy if you added 「目{め}」 and 「の」.  Using 「の」 is still possible, but using「目」 is not when the counters are already numbered.

「来{き}てください」 is not as polite as it might look.  A clerk/teller would use 「お越{こ}しください」 or 「お願{ねが}いいたします」.

> 「2番窓口**まで**お願いいたします。」

without using the verb "to come" would be the common announcement.